# Action requested: Declare your Ad ID permission

Tags: java, android, admob, google-play-console, google-advertising-id

Today i have got this email:

> Last July, we announced Advertising policy changes to help bolster
> security and privacy. We added new restrictions on identifiers used by
> apps that target children. When users choose to delete their
> advertising ID in order to opt out of personalization advertising,
> developers will receive a string of zeros instead of the identifier if
> they attempt to access the identifier. This behavior will extend to
> phones, tablets, and Android TV starting April 1, 2022. We also
> announced that you need to declare an AD_ID permission when you update
> your app targeting API level to 31 (Android 12). Today, we are sharing
> that we will give developers more time to ease the transition. We will
> require this permission declaration when your apps are able to target
> Android 13 instead of starting with Android 12.
>
> Action Items If you use an advertising ID, you must declare the AD_ID
> Permission when your app targets Android 13 or above. Apps that don’t
> declare the permission will get a string of zeros. Note: You’ll be
> able to target Android 13 later this year. If your app uses an SDK
> that has declared the Ad ID permission, it will acquire the permission
> declaration through manifest merge. If your app’s target audience
> includes children, you must not transmit Android Advertising ID (AAID)
> from children or users of unknown age.

My app is not using the Advertising ID. Should i declare the `AD_ID` Permission in Manifest or not?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

If your app uses the Google Mobile Ads SDK(**Admob**) version **20.4.0** or higher, you can skip setting up the permission manually since the SDK automatically declares it

More informations here:

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start

Comment: Yes, you are right bro, I'm using the latest Admob Sdk , i have checked my app merged manifest and found that the AD_ID Permission is exist,

Comment: My app doesn't contain ads still I need to add this ?

Comment: @Ysp , If your app don't contain Ads , then you don't have to do this.

Comment: The answer to this may be stupidly obvious, but it would be good to have clarification; I use AdMob through Firebase thusly: `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:20.6.0'` - as its version 20.6.0 I'm sure it's fine - but as its a redirect from Firebase I'd just like to know it's using AdMob's latest SDK?

Comment: @Jonathan that's not important if firebase uses the latest version or not as long as it version is higher than `20.4.0 `

Comment: My app doesn't target Android 13, it targets Android 10, API Level: 29. Should I declare AD_ID(by ugrading Admob SDK or Manifest)? (Besides, my Admob SDK is: play-services-ads:19.0.0)

Comment: @gurkanstack you should upgrade admob version to the latest version to avoid manual setting

Comment: Thanks for your response but I'm talking about targetSDK in Manifest. I don't think it is obligation to upgrade admob version or add ad_id to manifest if your app targets Android 10, API:29.

Comment: "Quick Start" from Google have this line "(Optional) Declare AD_ID permission for previous versions to work with Android 13." and just open it to update manifest for old version of Admob is good enough. Thanks friend.

Comment: If just use the `Play Services-ads`, can we just select No for the setup?

Comment: @Ysp, You can look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73132765/2289835) if your app doesn't contain ads.

Answer (score 175):

#### Case 1: The app doesn't contain any Ads:

You can simply remove/ignore it by adding **`tools:node="remove"`** in the `AndroidManifest.xml` file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" tools:node="remove"/>
```

Make sure you have `xmlns:tools` at the top of `AndroidManifest.xml` file :

```
<manifest xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" ... />
```

Even if another third-party library asks for this specific permission, the build will be forced not to merge it in your final Manifest file.
You can get more info [from this SO answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39353246/2289835)

---

#### Case 2: The app contains Ads:

Add the following to `AndroidManifest.xml` before `</manifest>`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>
```

You can get more information [from here.](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6048248)

Comment: It dosent's works for me :(

Comment: @TanvirAhmed you can find your final permission in a merged manifest file at `app/build/intermediates/manifests/full/debug/AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Careful, for me the merged manifest did NOT show the permission.AD_ID. I DID however see it in the decompiled APK and also saw it disappear there when adding the "remove" tag. Hope google play will stop complaining now.

Comment: I am building the app in flutter. And this solution is not working for me.

Comment: It' doesn't work for me too...

Comment: Please elaborate on the statement "Make sure you have xmlns:tools at the top of AndroidManifest.xml file" What exactly does this mean?

Comment: @Scorb, `tools:node="remove"` removes `com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID` permission from all the manifest files of other libraries at the time of manifest merging. You can find more info from [`tools:node="remove"` Node marker](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manage-manifests#node_markers), [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5856787/2289835) and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38202222/2289835).

Comment: if sb wonders about `xmlns:tool`, this is needed: `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`

Comment: I see the permission in merged manifest. How can I find what is adding it there as I  haven't used firebase or admob. I searched node_modules, but couldn't find there too.

Comment: @helloworld , It can be any of the libraries used in the project.

Comment: If you are still having problems while removing the permission from your app: I had to declare the remove tag from above inside both `manifest` and `application` to make all occurrences vanish. Yes, I placed the same line twice inside the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Answer (score 82):

#### Case 1: Your App has Ads

Add the following to `AndroidManifest.xml` before `</manifest>`:

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>
```

#### Case 2: Your App Doesn't have Ads

At the top of your `AndroidManifest.xml` make sure you have `xmlns:tools` on the `<manifest ...`>. (kudos to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55363172/2321594)) e.g.

```xml
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.mycompany.myapp">
```

Then, add the following at the bottom of the page, before `</manifest>` tag:

```xml
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" tools:node="remove"/>
```

#### Source:

- Google's Doc: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/ads/identifier/AdvertisingIdClient.Info#public-methods

Comment: It does not work for me :'( I still have the warning about com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID

Comment: Your Source gives me this error "Service Unavailable"

Comment: Adding `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` is important. Without it, my app would fail to compile. Thanks!

Comment: If you are still having problems while removing the permission from your app: I had to declare the remove tag from above inside both `manifest` and `application` to make all occurrences vanish. Yes, I placed the same line twice inside the `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: It doesn't work to me!

Answer (score 46):

In my case, I used `Firebase Analytics` only for crash reports etc.

**You can set your app to use advertising ID.**

[image]

**And use Analytics only.**

[image]

Comment: how to visit this page ? can you please share it?

Comment: Actually, you should get an email with a link.

Comment: Working for me Thanks. +1
**App Content --> Advertising ID --> Yes --> analytics**

Facing when app targetSdk 33

Comment: This work for me... I m doing target sdk 33 (Android 13) requirement from google. 

When i upload to google play console, it suddenly got the error that require me to declare AD_ID permission at AndroidManifest, but I not even use it in my app...

After come here and found the solution, so it could be the Firebase Analytics..

Comment: This sounds as good solution. But how does it impact users? What's changed to users?

Answer (score 28):

If your app doesn't contain ads, make sure you complete the survey on [App content](https://play.google.com/console/app/app-content/summary) page (Policy > App content) in Play Console.

Just select the option: **No, my app does not contain ads**.

If you don't do that, you won't be able to upload new releases of your app to Google Play.

[image: Google Play Console Ad Selector Location]

Answer (score 27):

Google describe here how to solve

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6048248?hl=en

Add in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>
```

Comment: So we have to update all of our apps adding this permission? And what happen if we don't update our apps?

Comment: Can I use AD_ID variable, e.g. like this `<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.@string/admob_appId"/>` ? Thanks

Comment: @spcsLrg, No need ,, Just add <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>

Comment: @joan16v it was requirements from Google if your build target api from 31. Check here https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/sdks/android/dai/android-12 . You don't have to do anything if your target api still <= 30

Answer (score 17):

First of all,
`com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID` can be added by other third party SDK like

- `Play Services-ads`
- `firebase-analytics` etc

So, if you haven't added `permission.AD_ID` manually, make sure it is not added by any other SDK by checking `merged manifest` file.
`merged-manifest` path:
`project` > `app` > `build` > `intermediate` > `merged_manifest` > `release` > `AndroidManifest.xml` 
Now go to your `play console` > `app content` > `Adverstising ID` and

- Select `NO` if your merged manifest doesn't contain `AD_ID`, else
- Select `YES` and complete next option.

Answer (score 11):

Don't worry. All developer who uses Admob for advertisement received this warning. Just make sure you are using **Latest** Google Mobile Ads SDK(Admob) OR AdMob SDK version **higher or equal to 20.4.0** in your `build.gradle` file. In that case **SDK automatically manage it**.

Otherwise **for older sdk below 20.4.0**, we need to manually mention below line in our AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>
```

Answer (score 8):

There are two different forms:

1. Ads
2. Advertising ID

Initially, I got stuck because I did not notice the other. So your app can be in any combination, for example, no ads, but yes, advertising ID.

In this [documentation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9857753) it is explained that Google services can include the advertising ID for other reasons that are not ads: Analytics.

> Google Play Services version 4.0 introduced new APIs and an ID for use by advertising and analytics providers. Terms for the use of this ID are below.

And in this other [documentation](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9859455?visit_id=638011990045978863-3874455370&rd=1#ads), in the examples section is very clear that ads are understood as what is commonly understood as ads: banners, pop-ups, a tile in the middle of a list, etc.

Analyzing the merged manifest we can see that the library  `play-services-measurement-api` is adding the permission and is related to Analytics. The library manifest looks like this:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" />

    <application>
        <service
            android:name="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService"
            android:exported="false" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.analytics.connector.internal.AnalyticsConnectorRegistrar"
                android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
        </service>
    </application>
```

Please notice that library is registering `analytics.connector.internal.AnalyticsConnectorRegistrar`.

In this case the Ads form must be mark with no but the Adverising ID form must be mark with yes and then the Analytics option.

I have seen people recommending force the manifest to not merge the `permission.AD_ID` but that would break the Analytics.

Comment: This actually is the right answer - the difference between Ads & Advertising ID. Thanks for this hint - solved my problem.

Comment: It is confusing because why would the advertising ID would be included by default in Analytics? Seems like a misnomer to me, if not reading multiple documentations is hard to figure it out @5ulo

Answer (score 6):

In case this is caused by for example firebase analytics which uses Advertising ID do not use `<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" tools:node="remove"/>` as shown in many other answers because analytics may not work correctly. Rather update declaration in Play Store Console that your app uses Advertising ID and select Analytics as reason. This will not add "App contains add" sentence for your app in Play Store.

Answer (score 5):

when you set `targetSdkVersion 33` you must need to add the below line in the manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" tools:node="remove"/>
```

if you are not set this, show a warning on the play console when your is in production.

Answer (score 3):

I also received today's mail from the PlayStore team to all developers. Asking to declare AD_ID permission.
Since we developed and released our application using `Flutter` with android targeting to API level 31. I'm using the `advertising_identifier: ^0.1.1` plugin to get the advertising client ID. I haven't declared AD_ID permission in my manifest file.

Additionally, apps updating their target API level to 31 (Android 12) and using advertise identifier / advertise id client info fetch will need to declare a Google Play services normal permission in the manifest file as follows:

`<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>`

Refered,

https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/6048248?hl=en

Comment: My app is developed using Flutter, I don't use any ad plugins like advertising_identifier. Should I add permission line in manifest file without changing AD_ID? What is AD_ID?
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>
Is there any thing to do for my flutter app related to "Action requested: Declare your Ad ID permission"?

Comment: AD_ID(Advertising ID) is the unique ID to track the user's movements & usages of applications. To access the application adID on iOS ASIdentifierManger.advertisingIdentifier and advertisingID on Android. As per the google play service doc, this AD_ID permission will be enforced starting from April 1st, 2022 for all devices. Android 12 users have the feature to delete their phones Advertising ID. So that's why android targeting level to 31 and more must need to provide permission to access the AD_ID. If your app doesn't contain ads not required to give.