# Action requested: Declare your Ad ID permission, is for Admob?

Tags: permissions, admob, ads

I received this mail today, and i'm not using Admob ads, i'm ussing applovin and Facebook i have to add this permission or is only for the developers that they use Admob?

Everyone received same mail even don't have admob like me?

> Hello Google Play Developer,
>
> Last July, we announced Advertising policy changes to help bolster
> security and privacy. We added new restrictions on identifiers used by
> apps that target children.
>
> When users choose to delete their advertising ID in order to opt out
> of personalization advertising, developers will receive a string of
> zeros instead of the identifier if they attempt to access the
> identifier. This behavior will extend to phones, tablets, and Android
> TV starting April 1, 2022.
>
> We also announced that you need to declare an AD_ID permission when
> you update your app targeting API level to 31 (Android 12). Today, we
> are sharing that we will give developers more time to ease the
> transition. We will require this permission declaration when your apps
> are able to target Android 13 instead of starting with Android 12.
>
> Action Items
>
> If you use an advertising ID, you must declare the AD_ID Permission
> when your app targets Android 13 or above. Apps that don’t declare the
> permission will get a string of zeros. Note: You’ll be able to target
> Android 13 later this year. If your app uses an SDK that has declared
> the Ad ID permission, it will acquire the permission declaration
> through manifest merge. If your app’s target audience includes
> children, you must not transmit Android Advertising ID (AAID) from
> children or users of unknown age. Learn more.
>
> Thank you,

Thank you!

Comment: [This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73132765/2289835) may help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't worry. All developer who uses Admob for advertisement received this warning. Just make sure you are using Latest Google Mobile AdMob SDK version higher or equal to 20.4.0 in your build.gradle file. In that case SDK automatically manage it.

Otherwise for older sdk below 20.4.0, we need to manually mention below line in our AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>

Comment: The thing is that i'm not using Admob. Then i have to add that permission or is not necessary?

Answer (score 2):

If your app does not need the advertising ID, then ignore that mail.
Otherwise, and if your targeting api level is 33 or above, add the permission line mentioned by @Umer Shahzad

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).