# We found ad SDKs in your app (Google Play)

Tags: android, flutter, google-play, admob, ads

We don't show ads or use ad SDK in our app. But when we upload to Google Play for publish, we get "We found ad SDKs in your app" warning. That's why we had to add the phrase "Contains Advertising" to the app.

I want to remove this phrase . We use Flutter. I think it's in the packages we use. How can I edit?

Also, yesterday we received an e-mail subject "Action requested: Declare your Ad ID permission" containing the following items. Do I need to do anything for this?

• If you use an advertising ID, you must declare the AD_ID Permission when your app targets Android 13 or above. Apps that don't declare the permission will get a string of zeros. Note: You'll be able to target Android 13 later this year.

• If your app uses an SDK that has declared the Ad ID permission, it will acquire the permission declaration through manifest merge.

Comment: [This SO answer may help you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73132765/2289835)

Comment: Were you able to figure this out? I am on the same boat right now.