# Why are my Admob Ads Not Showing in my Live Android App

Tags: android, admob, google-play-console, applicationid

I just released a game to the Google Plat store but my Admob Ads are not showing. Some easy answers:

- My target SDK is 33, and my complileSDK is also 33
- My app has been live since in the Play Store since Friday 2/3/23
- Yes - The Test Ads show when I used the test units
- Yes I switched to the real ad unit code for the release
- Yes - I officially connected my App to my Admob Account.
- In my AdMob account I don't see any warnings (besides the one about my payments are on hold - but that is because I haven't earned the minimum threshold for payment)

I made the connection to Admob Sunday morning (2/5/23) and I got this email:

> We completed our app review. The following app has been approved, and
> we’ve lifted the ad serving limits and restrictions put in place
> during the review.

Yes - I have the latest implementation code in my build gradle (in the dependencies brackets):

`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:21.4.0'`

Again, the Google AdMob test ads show, so in my Manifest I have (in the meta-data):

```
android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
android:value="ca-app-pub-account_number"
```

In my Main_Activity file I use the Ad Unit ID.

In looking for a solution for this I came across this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71473553/action-requested-declare-your-ad-id-permission) earlier, so I added this code to the Manifest as well:

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID"/>
```

My app creates non-personalized ads like so:

```
private void createNonPersonalizedAd(Animation slideOutToLeft) {

        Bundle networkExtrasBundle = new Bundle();
        networkExtrasBundle.putInt("rdp", 1);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
                .addNetworkExtrasBundle(AdMobAdapter.class, networkExtrasBundle)
                .build();

        createInterstitialAd(adRequest, slideOutToLeft);
    }
```

In my Google Play Console I answered **"YES"** to the following question:

> Does your app use advertising ID?

Reason:

> Analytics or Marketing

I'm not sure if there is value in pasting all of the code from the Main_Activity that calls the ads, especially since the test ads display OK.

- I'm not sure if I declared something wrong in the Play Console that conflicts.
- About an hour ago (on 2/6/23) I connected Firebase to my app
- I'm not sure if it takes more time to display ads or I have configured something wrong
- Can anyone identify what I've done wrong that prevents the ads from showing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get some outside help and thus discovered the issue was that Google had not approved my Admob account. This was not reflected in my account though, because everything there looked ready to go - and I got the email from Google saying my app was approved and ready to show ads.

I was browsing other forums where someone mentioned to check Adsense. I went to my Adsense account and saw that again I wasn't approved yet for payments. I had submitted that information before - but I resubmitted my government ID, EIN, incorporation paperwork and then my banking information. Once that was submitted, my ads began to show in my apps.

So the issue wasn't technical. It was just Adsense needing information about my company. I hope this answer helps someone else out.

Comment: Does your government ID name have to match the name used in your payment information?

Comment: My payment information is for a company. So Google is not paying me, they are paying directly. So maybe they don't need a match, maybe they just need a govt ID to tie to the account in case there are any future issues. Then they can tie it back to a real person. Hope this helps.