# Kivy Apps targeting Android 13, advertising ID, and adding permission in the manifest

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer

Google has this warning when I submit my app. I want to make sure I get ontop of this before they start rejecting my app. My app is written in Python with Kivy, and it's compiled using Buildozer

"Apps targeting Android 13 or above and use advertising ID must include the com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission in the manifest."

My app doesn't have adds, but I would like to know what to do for either situation.

This post for non Kivy/Python apps says we need to edit AndroidManifest.xml, but I have not seen this xml file before.

[Action requested: Declare your Ad ID permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71473553/action-requested-declare-your-ad-id-permission)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71473553/7874746 Follow this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. I figured out how to declare no Ad ID in the Google Play Consol.

Touch the top-left menu and scroll all the way down to Policy status