# What are "ramifications of not including the com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission in the manifest file when targeting Android 13"?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I'm developing mobile apps using Unity. After installing Firebase Unity SDK, I get the error message when trying to upload by app to Google Play Console:

> Google Api Error: Invalid request - This release includes the com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID_ID permission but your declaration on Play Console says your app doesn't use advertising ID. You muupdD permission but your declaratiost update your advertising ID declaration.

This error is a frequently reported on stackoverflow. However, my question concerns the official solution proposed by google:

- I went to Google Play Console -> App Content -> AdvertisingID -> Manage
- There I opted:

  - Does your app use advertising ID? -> yes -> check "Analytics"
  - AND ALSO:

I understand the ramifications of not including the com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission in the manifest file when targeting Android 13 and would like to turn off release errors

- After this the error, when trying to create a new release, went away.

However, I don't understand the "ramifications"! Also today that checkbox has disappeared, so I cannot undo it anymore.

Can someone help me answering the following question:  Does my choice of "I would like to turn off release errors" imply that errors are simply ignored and I don't have a fully functional firebase-analytics setup anymore?

I want firebase analytics to send useful data to google analytics to help my AI based app-campaign which is based on data gathered by firebase-analytics. How can I make sure I didn't break something?

Post-Question:

- I don't want to [follow the suggestions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73170802/2191652) given in other stackoverflow answers for disabling ad id via

  `<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" tools:node="remove"/>`

in my manifest for the above mentioned reason.

- I'm using:

  - Unity: 2022.3.4f1
  - Firebase Unity SDK: 11.6.0