# How to Resolve Missing AD_ID Permission Warning in Android Manifest?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-permissions, google-advertising-id

[![enter image description here][1]][1] hereI'm encountering a warning in the Google Play Console regarding the missing com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission in my AndroidManifest.xml file. Despite having declared the AD_ID permission, I'm still receiving this warning.

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID" />
```

However, the Play Console continues to prompt me with the warning:

> "Your advertising ID declaration in Play Console says that your app
> uses advertising ID. A manifest file in one of your active artifacts
> doesn't include the com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID
> permission."

I've verified that the package name in my manifest matches the one in the Play Console. Is there something I'm missing or misunderstanding about this permission declaration? Any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: As the error clearly states: "A manifest file in one of your active artifacts doesn't include the com.google.android.gms.permission.AD_ID permission.". Meaning, that one of the dependencies your application is using, which uses the advertising id, has not declared this permission. You can share your build.gradle file and see which libraries you are using. That way, you can look at the version and see if it contains the required permission.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73132765/2442831

Comment: @Lino it does not work for me

Comment: @SafiqRahmanS - I don't understand your comment.

Comment: @tomerpacific build.gradle libraries using ads          implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:23.0.0'         implementation 'com.google.android.ads:mediation-test-suite:3.0.0'

Comment: @SafiqRahmanS - What other dependencies do you have in your build.gradle file?

Comment: @tomerpacific please check above

Comment: @SafiqRahmanS - That is a lot of dependencies. Have you checked all of them in relation to the permission for AD_ID?

Comment: i have already checked @tomerpacific

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257222/discussion-between-safiq-rahman-s-and-tomerpacific).